# How can i override css property

Tags: jquery, css, overriding

How can i override css property with javascript/jQuery, like cssHooks(jQuery), but prop was in external css.

e.g.

index.html

```
<div id="test">abc</div>
```

styles.css

```
#test {background: red;}
```

and every time I use background prop I want to hide this elem and do nothing with background.

"but I want to do it not only for certain div (#test) but for every element with background prop in my css"

Comment: What do you mean "hide this...and do nothing with background"?

Comment: Please restate your question including the comment made to the answers.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question.

Comment: I don't get it, do you wan't to hide every element with a red background, or every element with a background set? Exactly what do you mean by hide the element and do nothing with background, you do realise the background will disappear when hiding the element, and unless you programaticly change the background, it will be the same when hiding/showing elements. As for hiding elements with a certain background, that would mean iterating over all elements and checking the background property, and it would be very inefficient.

Comment: I want to "change things that are using the background property"

Comment: My answer reflects your updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using jquery, you can just do

```
$('#test').css('display','none');
```

That will hide the element and leave the background untouched.

**[Edit]** I don't think I understood the question before. Per your comment, what you want to do is change things that are using the `background` property? I don't believe there is a way to do this. The only option I can think of is to loop through every single DOM element and check if if has a element.style.background set.

Comment: but I want to do it not only for certain div (#test) but for every element with background prop in my css

Comment: "what you want to do is change things that are using the background property?" - yes(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide elements that have the css property `background` set it would be best to add a class to these elements. Then hide the element based on the class.

The example below hides all items with the class `background-set`.

```
$('.background-set').hide();
```

The worse way would be to grab elements and filter out if the `background` property isn't  set. I started the search with a div selector but you can expand that as needed.

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background').replace('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%','').length > 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Second function won't work, see my answer, good thinking though!

Answer (score 0):

Style values set directly on the element will override things set in CSS.  If you want to hide the element, you can do so like this:

```
$('#test').hide();
```

Internally, this is just a shortcut for setting `elem.style.display = "none";`.

This part of your question has us confused: "every time I use background prop I want to hide this elem and do nothing with background." so if you need more to the answer, you will need to clarify what you were asking.

hiding the element does not change the background in any way (though it will no longer be visible).  If you're trying to hide the background while keeping the element visible, then you would need to set the background back to transparent.

```
$('#test').css("background", "transparent");
```

Setting this style value directly on the element will override any CSS stylesheet rules you have set.

Answer (score 0):

When using javascript to check the background property, different browsers will return different values. Chrome returns `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%` for an element with no background set, so checking the length of the returned string will not work, other browser may not have rgba support and return something else.

All you really have to do is check to see if the background property matches the above, atleast for Chrome, and then figure out what other browsers return as well, and do something really inefficient like:

```
var pattern=/rgba\(0\, 0\, 0\, 0\)/gi;

$.each($('*'), function(index, item) {
    var bg = $(item).css('background');
    if (!bg.match(pattern)) {
        $(item).hide();
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/CunWL/3/)